# Compilation keeps running (pattern, matcher task)

Tags: java, regex, loops, compilation

When I run the program, it keeps running and console is active for input, so I have to push stop. Why is that?
(taks is to find mirrored words in sentence. Using INTELIJ IDEA).

```
public class Blinov11 {

    static String mirror(String str){
        String mirrored = "";
        for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            mirrored += str.charAt(i);
        }
        return mirrored;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text = new String("If the method atad fi takes data a sekat takes primitive data type as an argument, then the nhet String object representing the primitive data type value is return.");
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\W\\w+\\W",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        String word = "";
        while(matcher.find()){
            word = mirror(matcher.group());
            if(text.contains(word)){
                System.out.println(word);
            }
        matcher.reset();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is due to the fact that you're calling:

```
matcher.reset();
```

inside your `while loop`. As per [Java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#reset%28%29):

> `public Matcher reset()`
>
> Resets this matcher. **Resetting a matcher
>   discards all of its explicit state information and sets its append
>   position to zero.** The matcher's region is set to the default region,
>   which is its entire character sequence. The anchoring and transparency
>   of this matcher's region boundaries are unaffected.

Because of `reset()` in your `while` loop, matcher gets reset every time and `while (matcher.find())` becomes an infinite loop since it always finds from start position.